# Linux command to replace spaces with -(dash) from directories name recursevily?

Tags: linux, replace, find, command, batch-rename

How to replace spaces with -(dash) from directory name in Linux using command line?

**Note:** There are hundreds of directories and all of them have sub directories too.

I have tried below command but it return a message ***'call: rename from to files...'*** and all names are still unchanged.

```
find /home/jjj/ddd -name "* *" -type d | rename 's/ /-/g'
```

I would like Change the "*Directory Name*" to "*Directory-Name*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using shell instead rename

```
find /home/jjj/ddd -depth -name "* *" -type d -print0 | while read -d $'\0' dir; do mv -v "$dir" "${dir// /-}"; done
```

> added `-depth` to make it proper as per requirement.

Comment: sure...i will update the result here in a few minutes. thanks

Comment: its working but need a little modification to make it work properly for recursively.
**we need to rename the sub directory first then parents.**.

`/home/jjj/ddd/New f o l d e r' -> `/home/jjj/ddd/New-f-o-l-d-e-r'
mv: cannot stat `/home/jjj/ddd/New f o l d e r/New folder': No such file or directory

Comment: And the final Command is 
    
**find /home/jjj/ddd -depth -name "* *" -type d -print0 | while read -d $'\0' dir; do mv -v "$dir" "${dir// /-}"; done**